# Как реализовать парсер главных новостей на python?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, bs4

Всем Добрый день.Подскажите как реализовать парсер главных новостей новостного  [портала](https://www.zakon.kz/).Чтобы все главные новости этого сайта парсились и автоматически записывались в БД.

Подскажите  с чего стоит начать реализацию ?

А еще хотел сказать что у меня есть парсер,но он парсит только определенные странички как его можно модернизировать ?

Вот код моего парсера который парсит определённые странницы

```
#Парсер v0
import requests
import dateparser
import pymysql.cursors
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

def get_data(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    title=soup.find('h1').text
    text=soup.find('p').text
    date=soup.find('span',{'class':'news_date'}).text
    textp=soup.find_all('p')


    date=dateparser.parse(date, date_formats=['%d %B %Y %H'])

    #print(title)
    #print(text)
    #print(date)
    #print(str(textp))
    return  (title,text,date,str (textp))

def main():
    url = 'https://www.zakon.kz/4979527-shestnadtsatiletniy-kibersportsmen.html'
    (get_data(get_html(url)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

#SQL
# Подключение к базе данных.
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='root',
                             password='',
                             db='pars',
                             charset='utf8',
                             autocommit=True)
print ("connect successful!!")


url = 'https://www.zakon.kz/4979527-shestnadtsatiletniy-kibersportsmen.html'
array = get_data(get_html(url))

sql = "insert into gag (`title`, `text`, `time`,`textp`) values (%s,%s,%s,%s)"
cursor=connection.cursor()

title =array[0]
text=array[1]
date=str(array[2])
textp=array[3]




cursor.execute(sql,(str(title),str(text),str(date),str(textp)))

print ("Connect successful!")
```

Comment: *Подскажите с чего стоит начать реализацию ?* С общения с администрацией портала. Вдруг у них есть API, к примеру? или готовая реализация парсера, который они могут отдать (или дать контакты автора, или ещё что)...

Comment: RSS у них точно есть: https://www.zakon.kz/rss.xml

Comment: Видите ли,мне такой вариант не подойдет.Мне надо чтобы именно парсил работал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо кто помогал и советовал! Нашел способ реализации.(прошу не кидаться камнями за такой код)

```
#Парсер v1 by Raha
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin


def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    if r.ok: # 200  ## 403 404
        return r.text
    print(r.status_code)


def get_page_link(url, html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    title =soup.find('h1',{'class':'roboto'}).text
    link_containers=soup.findAll('div',{'class':'cat_news_item'})
    print(str.strip(title))


    counter = 0
    for link_container in link_containers:
        a_tag = link_container .find("a")
        # Если нашел
        if a_tag:
            link = a_tag.get("href")
            print(urljoin(url, link))
        else:
            counter += 1
    print(f"Ошибок нашлось {counter}")


def main():
    url = 'https://www.zakon.kz/news/'
    get_page_link(url, get_html(url))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```